# How to execute the java program of apache thrift (with ant if possible)

Tags: java, ant, command-line, compiler-errors, javac

I have thrift installed on my system at `~/thrift` if someone can help me how to compile it with `ant` that would be great

I have done the following with command line.

I have written an apache thrift program and can execute it in eclipse. I want to do it from commandline.

My tree structure of my base directory is:

```
.
├── bin
├── lib
│   ├── commons-codec-1.6.jar
│   ├── commons-lang3-3.1.jar
│   ├── commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
│   ├── httpclient-4.2.5.jar
│   ├── httpcore-4.2.4.jar
│   ├── junit-4.4.jar
│   ├── libthrift-0.9.1.jar
│   ├── log4j-1.2.14.jar
│   ├── servlet-api-2.5.jar
│   ├── slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
│   └── slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
└── src
    ├── FileMetaData.java
    ├── files
    ├── FileStoreImpl.java
    ├── FileStore.java
    ├── RFile.java
    ├── RFileMetadata.java
    ├── Server.java
    ├── Status.java
    ├── StatusReport.java
    └── SystemException.java

4 directories, 20 files
```

`src/Server.java` has the `main` function to execute.

I compile using the following command:

```
javac -classpath "lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" -d bin src/*.java -Xlint:none
```

It generates the following warning:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

But I am OK with it since I just want to execute it locally and I already have executed it in eclipse and knows it works.

To run from command line I tried this command:

```
cd bin
java Server
```

OR this

```
java -classpath "lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:lib‌​/log4j-1.2.14.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:bin" Server
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Just a context: I have to submit this as an assignment and I should provide a script which compiles the files and runs it on another machine of the instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath, the same as you used for compiling:

You need to stay on the top level folder of your project (the parent of `bin` and `lib`) and add `bin` to the classpath.

```
java -classpath "bin:lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:lib‌​/log4j-1.2.14.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" Server
```

You could pack your classes into an own jar and add it to the classpath.

**EDIT**

Sample ant build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project-template" basedir="." default="package">
    <!-- properties  -->
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="bin" value="bin" />
    <property name="lib" value="lib" />
    <property name="dist" value="dist" />
    <property name="java.version.target" value="1.6" />
    <property name="main.class" value="com.client.ClientMain" />
    <property name="jarfile" value="${ant.project.name}.jar" />

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- target package: create the jar file -->
    <target name="package" depends="compile">
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/${jarfile}" basedir="${bin}">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- target compile: compile the source files -->
    <target name="compile" depends="prepare">
        <javac includeantruntime="false"
            srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" debug="false" optimize="true" 
            target="${java.version.target}">
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all -verbose -deprecation"/>
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Create build directories as needed -->
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${bin}" includes="**/*" />
            <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: @footy, I see the problem, when you are in `bin` and try to run your program you cannot access `lib/*`, this wont even work if you do `ls lib`. Within `bin` you have to add `../` to each entry in the classpath. Better yet return to the top level of your project and add `bin` the the classpath. See my edit.

Comment: I am doing it from the top-level directory itself and added bin to class path. it still doesnt work

Comment: It would be great if I can get `ant` to compile and run this.

Comment: @footy, Why bother with ant when you have Eclipse? just export your project as `Runnable jar` and choose `Package required libraries into generated JAR`

Comment: I have to submit this as an assignment and I should provide a script which compiles the files and runs it on another machine of the instructor.

Comment: @footy, check my edit! (set name of your project, main.class and java.version.target), run using `java -jar dist\project-template.jar`. The Ant scrip packages all the jars in lib into the the result jar `dist\project-template.jar`. This is not actually the way to go, instead you should package only your own code and when running you have to specify third party libs using the `-classpath` option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38380/discussion-between-footy-and-a4l)